# changing colors of HTML elements with skeleton

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

can someone tell me how I can change for example the background-color globaly. 
I made it with ''. Whitout skeleton I would do it classic with a style.css file based in css directory.

When I try to change the body entrys in the skeleton.css file, nothing happened :(

What is the to do for skeleton?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skeleton doesn't change anything about how html and css will interact. Skeleton is basically just pre-built css file. You can still include styles.css with a second link tag, i.e.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skelton.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>
```